# Typescript 3+ features not working even though Typescript 3+ version is installed

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors, tsconfig

I have typescript 3.7.3 installed globally and Visual Code is using Typescript version 3.7.3 but I can't seem to access Typescript 3+ functionality. For instance when trying to declare a variable with the type "unknown" I get a compile error: "Cannot find name 'unknown'. Even though it seems to be avalable as a suggestion in intellisence. How can I troubleshoot this?

[image]

My tscongif.json is:

```
{
 "compileOnSave": false,
 "compilerOptions": {
   "baseUrl": "./",
   "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
   "sourceMap": true,
   "declaration": false,
   "downlevelIteration": true,
   "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,   // Needed for Stackblitz
   "experimentalDecorators": true,
   "module": "esnext",
   "moduleResolution": "node",
   "importHelpers": true,
   "target": "es2015",
   "typeRoots": [
     "node_modules/@types"
   ],
   "lib": [
     "es2018",
     "dom"
   ]
 },
 "angularCompilerOptions": {
   "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
   "strictInjectionParameters": true
 }
}
```

Comment: If you build via the command line are you also seeing this error? Or is it only within Visual Studio Code?

Comment: It's only within VS code. And the intellisense knows the type and offers auto-completion, but once added it is marked as red with the error code as shown in the image.

Answer (score 0):

A version of TypeScript is likely also being installed to your `node-modules` folder.

`tsc -v` is reporting the *globally* installed version. Visual Studio Code will also have it's own version of the TypeScript compiler.

Check in `/node-modules/typescript/package.json` for the actual `{ "version": "X.X.X" }` of TypeScript that will be used.

Your projects `package.json` file will define:

```
"devDependencies": {
    ...
    "typescript": "X.X.X" <- update this.
  }
```

Comment: Thanks I have checked this. I've now installed version 3.4.3 globally and set VS Code to use it and in my package.json I have "typescript": "^3.4.3". Still I get: "cannot find name 'unknown'".

Comment: Is there anything else that can overrun it? If I understand it correctly there is a typescript language service that VS code uses and that points just as you mentioned to the typescript files in node_modules: In settings.json I have "typescript.tsdk": "node_modules\\typescript\\lib"